# How necessary is a List of Figures and a List of Tables in a dissertation?

Tags: thesis, formatting

I am writing my dissertation (word-limit 10,000 words) and am wondering if I should include a separate *List of Figures* and *List of Tables* Section after my Table of Contents? The university guidelines do not specify whether they're required or not.

I will have about 3 figures and 4 tables when I'm finished.

Comment: Then do whatever you like (after asking your supervisor/advisor of course).

Answer (score 6):

To be honest, with a short dissertation with only a few figures and tables, it probably doesn't really matter one way or the other.

If your institution's dissertation guidelines say anything about it, follow them.  If not, I'd say just include the lists, unless you feel you have some good reason not to.  In which case, don't.  Your advisor should let you know if they believe such lists should be added or removed, anyway.

Or you could just ask your advisor about it to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely ask your advisor but normally you only need a list of tables or a list of figures if there will be more than 5 items in the list. For three or four items, I would not include a list.

However, in the schools I am familiar with, there are clear dissertation guidelines so it is understood what is expected. If it is unspecified then I would go with what I said above.